# How to redirect traffic of a url pattern to a specific file in Jetty?

Tags: java, jetty, web.xml, redirect

I have a embedded Jetty server in my REST service.  My web.xml is currently like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-services</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>service.contracts;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-services</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I'd like to redirect all urls that are not of the pattern `/services/*` to my welcome file instead of returning a 404.  Do I need to write another servlet to do that?  Or is there a simpler way?

My reason for doing so is to allow for html5's push state to work without `#`, which will require the server to return the index file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need another servlet with a url mapping to "/*" to do the redirection in your situation